# How to send a type parameter as a function argument

Tags: scala, implicit, circe

I caught myself repeatedly using a similar piece of code for JSON unmarshalling. The only difference between the snippets was the type parameter in a function call. Consequently, I tried to write a function to improve code reuse, but I cannot seem to get it to compile. What I'm attempting to do is shown below.

```
/** Decode a GET response by unmarshalling its JSON payload.
 * @tparam R The type of Response to unmarshall into.
 * @param response The GET response to decode.
 * @return Try[R] if decoding was successful, else Failure[Throwable] */
private def decodeResponse[R <: Response](response: HttpResponse): Try[R] = {
  val payload = decode[R](response.text)
  logger.debug(s"Decoded payload: $payload")
  payload.toTry
}
```

As you can see, I wish to specify a type `R` as part of my return type and part of my function body. I believe it is the latter which is causing compilation to fail, but I am unsure of how to fix it. An example of an `R` would be `SearchResponse`, the case class definition for which extends the `Response` trait.

I've performed several searches into type parameters, but no results use type parameters in function bodies. Additionally, I've searched for the exception that is being thrown upon compilation:

```
Error:(72, 28) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type io.circe.Decoder[R]
    val payload = decode[R](response.text)
```

However, all results lead to solutions for specific libraries that caused these problems, which unfortunately isn't of use for me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `[R <: Response : Decoder]`

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! Any clue where I might find more information about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decode[R] function requires an implicit parameter of type `Decoder[R]`. To make your code compile, you need to add this implicit parameter to your own function:

```scala
private def decodeResponse[R <: Response](response: HttpResponse)(implicit decoder: Decoder[R]): Try[R] = …
```

Passing an implicit parameter `Foo[A]` for some type parameter `A` is a very common occurrence, which is why they came up with a terser syntax for this use case: Context bounds.
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html
All it means is that when you write this

```
def foo[A: Foo] = …
```

it will be equivalent to this:

```
def foo[A](implicit f: Foo[A])
```